# Windows Devices for non-store application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile

I'd like to access the accelerometer on a windows device if it's available. However, I am not building the device for windows store. Is there a way to access this and other sensors from a desktop environment? What reference do I include?

Comment: Very unclear question: What is a windows store?

Comment: http://www.windowsstore.com/

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Sensor and Location API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463473.aspx) supports desktop usage, including from Windows 7.

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't answered my question. What referrence do I need include what is to be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to add any resources to your project.  The only thing that you may need is to call required namespace. Which are :

```
using Microsoft.Devices.Sensors;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
```

You may also have a look at this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431810%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)